# Permutation mapping : binary Hamming code

Tags: matlab, matrix, hamming-code

I have a binary Hamming code with generator matrix

```
 G = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1;
      0 1 0 0 1 1 1;
      0 0 1 0 1 1 0;
      0 0 0 1 0 1 1];
```

and `u` is a received vector  `u = [0.5 0.3 1.3 -0.1 0.7 0.6 1.5]`.

The permutation received vector based on decreasing values is :

`v = p(u) = [1.5 1.3 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.3 -0.1]`
with `p = (5 6 2 7 3 4 1)`.

The permuted generator matrix is :

```
G1 = [1 0 1 0 1 0 0;
      1 0 1 1 0 1 0;
      0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
      1 0 0 1 0 0 1];
```

I tried to program this example but I do not find exactly the same answer, I find `p` different but the same `v` and `G1`.

My code :

```
G = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1;
     0 1 0 0 1 1 1;
     0 0 1 0 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 1 0 1 1];

u = [0.5 0.3 1.3 -0.1 0.7 0.6 1.5];
[~,p] = sort(u,'descend');
v = u(p);
G1 = G(:,[p]);
```

I obtain :

```
v = [1.5 1.3 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.3 -0.1];
p = [7 3 5 6 1 2 4]; 

G1 = [1 0 1 0 1 0 0;
      1 0 1 1 0 1 0;
      0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
      1 0 0 1 0 0 1];
```

What is the problem in my code? I would like to have the same results as in the example.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the example from?

Comment: The permutation vector that you propose is incorrect.  What MATLAB gives is the right result if you are looking for the indices based on decreasing values.  In your answer, location `5`, or `u(5) = 0.7` would be considered the highest value and that is not correct.  It's actually the last value, so that's 7 and thus `u(7) = 1.5`.  Double check your expected vector `p` and make sure it aligns with your definition of "decreasing values".  If not, please edit your post to reveal the true nature of this permutation vector.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng - Reinstate Monica.